# Excel Macro is only copying "false" value of a logic statement

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I used the Macro Recorder to create a macro to copy files from one worksheet to a second worksheet and reset a form to default values.

When the macro is run the "false" value ("NO") of a logic statement is copied regardless of the value in the cell at the time the macro is run. If I change the value in the false statement from "NO" to any other value (i.e. "Blue") it copies over the new value ("Blue").

Here is the formula for the logic statement:

```
=IF(AND(D15>VLOOKUP(C13,CCT,3,FALSE),D15<VLOOKUP(C13,CCT,4,TRUE)),"YES","NO")
```

where `CCT` is a list.

Here is the code for the macro:

```
Range("D17").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Worksheet2").Select
Range("G3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Worksheet1").Select
```

Comment: Why do you have single quotation marks around the less than sign?

Answer (score 0):

You might try Worksheet.Activate after you select different sheets.  Worksheet.Calculate might be in order as well.

I think that using Range...  implies  Activesheet.Range.    Hope it helps